# How can I use a custom css file in a custom module?

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, theme, css

I successfully created a custom theme and a custom module. Right now the module just outputs "Hello World" in the header panel of my shop. Now, I want to apply some styling to my block inside my module. The `default_head_blocks.xml`of my theme (located at `myTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/ 
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <css src="css/navbar-style.css"/>
</head>
</page>
```

The `default.xml` inside my module (located at `Test/Navbar/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
<css src="css/navbar-style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
<block class="Test\Navbar\Block\Navbar" name="test.navbar" template="Test_Navigation::default/navbar.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

My navbar.phtml (located at `Test/Navbar/view/frontend/templates/default/navbar.phtml`) looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
* Test navbar template
*
* @var $block TestNavbarBlockNavbar
*/
?>
<div class="r23-navbar">Hello World</div>
```

and finally the .css located at `app/design/frontend/test/testtheme/web/css/navbar-style.css`

looks like this:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.r23-header {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100px;
color: red;
}

body {
background-color: green;
}
```

The result is, that the body color of my whole Magento site is green. So the css is working. But how can I apply styling to my navbar.phtml? Because nothing happens there when I reload my site. I always clear the `var` and `pub/static` folder (except for the `.htaccess` file). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Yes, always. I mean the css works on the body. So adding head per `default_head_blocks.xml` works. But adding it to my .phtml doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Okey I solved it myself. I made the most rookie mistake ever. I named the .css class differently inside my PHTML and inside the actual CSS file. Now everything works. One was "r23-header" and the other one was "r23-navbar". I guess the longer you stare at something the less you see.

Comment: Rookie? Every developer i know does that about once a week........